# website region lock | Localize SEO traffic

Tags: seo, web-development

This may be a question that is completely out there but I'm about to publish a site that is very localize advertising - this can become big at some point but for right now I want to keep "out of state" traffic off it for branding and patent purposes. Is this even possible to keep traffic from inside the US entering my site? I am looking to optimize keywords but just don't need someone from Ohio if this website is only for California.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question right, you need to target your site to a narrow region.
If you use SEO, try to use keywords that describe your site as a resource of only region you need, like shoes for californians or big discounts in Oregon. Use it in your content, meta info, indound links and inner linking.
If you use PPC to advertise, like Google Adwords, try to target campaign in System preferences. Also, use right keywords in your advertisement, which will help users to understand what is site targeted for before they will make click and spend your money.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how reliable using a GEO within a state is... In the UK its incredibly unreliable as take me for example: My IP is a UK one and I live in Bournemouth but my broadband company uses IP blocks that are issued by Birmingham, so blocking Bournemouth would not work.... and this could be the case for your customers.

So the answer is yes you can filter US customers and block EU/ASIA using a [GEO IP detection](http://www.maxmind.com/en/home) on your website, similar to how Google, Netflix detects their customers but state/region detection within countries can be unreliable and depends on the broadband company and you will need to check various ISPS within California and see what the LOOKUP returns.

Your first step should be discovering which ISPS are available in California and then finding out some of their IPS from customers in that state then using http://www.maxmind.com/en/home DEMO IP and seeing what results are returned. There is no easier method than this mentioned since Windows does not disclose this information.